# what is the difference between these two jQuery functions?

Tags: jquery, function, click, bind

what is the difference between these two jQuery functions?
**.bind**('**click**', … and **.click**( …

```
1. $("#div").bind('click', function(event) { });

2. $("#div").click(function() { });
```

Comment: [Have a look at the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/): *This method is a shortcut for `.bind('click', handler)` in the first two variations, and `.trigger('click')` in the third.*

Answer (score 5):

Nothing. The second is just a shortcut. `bind` is used when you're trying to listen to a less common event that doesn't have its own shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

***technically*** `bind` is faster since there is one less function call, but they're functionally identical.  Also, `.click()` can be used as a map to `.trigger()` if you don't pass a function:

```
$('#div').click(); === $('#div').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Between those two, there is no difference. However, if you'd use

```
$('#div').live('click', function(ev) { });
```

it would bind the event to any DOM object matching the selector now *or in the future*. That means, that if you load a div with id "div" using AJAX, the click-handler will automatically be wired up to your new div.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. `click` is just a convenience function that calls `bind('click', ...)`.